# Undo/redo in C++ Android memory leak

Tags: android, c++, memory-leaks

I am developing a finger painting app on Android. I implemented this finger painting in C++ together with page curling. The finger painting works well, but I want to know if there is any memory leak in my undoPen and redoPen methods. It has to be done with raw pointers. I have added the useful part of the code only.

```
vector<vector<*mPath>>MAIN(12);
vector<*mPath> undoMain(0);
int PageNo = 0;
void Pen::onFingerDown(float x1, float y1)
{
    undoMain.clear();

    MAIN[PageNo].push_back(move(path));
    mx = x1;
    my = y1;
    tempPoints.x1=x1;
    tempPoints.y1=y1;
    tempPoints.x2=x1;
    tempPoints.y2=y1;
    // points.push_back(tempPoints);
    path->addVert(tempPoints);
}

void Pen::onFingerMove(float x, float y)
{
    tempPoints.x1=mx;
    tempPoints.y1=my;
    tempPoints.x2=x;
    tempPoints.y2=y;
    path->addVert(tempPoints);

    // path->addColor(tempColors);
    // points.push_back(tempPoints);

    mx=x;
    my=y;
    //LOG_INFO("LOOOOOL");
}

void Pen::onFingerUp()
{
    path = new mPath();
}

void Pen::undoPen()
{
    if (MAIN[PageNo].size()>0) {
        undoMain.push_back(move(*MAIN[PageNo].erase(MAIN[PageNo].end()-1)));
    }

}

void Pen::redoPen()
{
    if (undoMain.size()>0) {
        MAIN[PageNo].push_back(move(*undoMain.erase(undoMain.end()-1)));

        ////
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile?  `vector<vector<*mPath>>MAIN(12);` is not valid syntax.

Comment: In the code shown there is 1 call to `new` and 0 calls to `delete`.  So you either have leaks or more code we need to see.

Comment: There are many tools which can spot memory leaks. Take a look at [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), for example.

Comment: Yes NathanOliver the code compiles. Richard path variable is deleted in the deconstructor of the class my main issues is with the undoPen and redoPen methods are there any memory leaks there.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't went through your code but of course you have memory leaks whenever you call new without the corresponding implicit or explicit delete, let's use smart pointers for that purpose. In adition:

```
 vector<vector<PathType>>MAIN(12); // *mPath should be a type, what is the type of mPath 
 vector<PathType> undoMain(0);
```

I would do it like this

```
 vector<vector<std::unique_ptr<PathType>>>MAIN(12); // 
 vector<std::unique_ptr<PathType>> undoMain(0);
```

or if both MAIN and undo undoMAIN shares the same data

```
vector<vector<std::shared_ptr<PathType>>>MAIN(12); // 
vector<std::shared_ptr<PathType>> undoMain(0);
```

Actually path is not defined in your sample code

EDIT:

I've been reworking my answer.

Firstly, maybe you should keep on learning and diving deeper in C++, and forget about managed code, your version is confusing. In fact we won't use smartpointers, everything can be copied without much side effects :

I give you a reworked version :

```
    typedef vector < fingerPos >            path_type;          // So you low level representation of a path

// Those two must have finite limits ( no more than a given configuration dependant number )
std::deque < path_type >            undo_History  ( 12 );   // no need to reserve anything here ( although you can ), user input are slow.
std::deque < path_type >            redo_History   ( 12 )

struct Path 
{
    path_type                       mlineHolder;

    Path() 
    { } 

    void addVert ( fingerPos vert ) 
    { 
        mlineHolder.push_back(vert); 
    }  

    vector < fingerPos > Path::getPath ( ) 
    { 
        return ( mlineHolder ); 
    }

    ~Path() 
    { 
        // no need it's automatic 
        // mlineHolder.clear();

        // copy the current path to the Undo buffer
        undo_History.push_back ( mlineHolder );     
    } 
};

void Pen::onFingerDown(float x1, float y1)
{
    // Don't undo when user begins a new drawing or you loose your buffers
    // undoMain.clear ( );

    // But clear the redo history since you cannot redo from something different
    redo_History.clear ( );

    mx = x1;
    my = y1;

    tempPoints.x1=x1;
    tempPoints.y1=y1;
    tempPoints.x2=x1;
    tempPoints.y2=y1;

    // points.push_back(tempPoints);
    m_path->addVert ( tempPoints );
}

void Pen::onFingerMove(float x, float y)
{
    tempPoints.x1=mx;
    tempPoints.y1=my;
    tempPoints.x2=x;
    tempPoints.y2=y;

    m_path->addVert(tempPoints);

    // path->addColor(tempColors);
    // points.push_back(tempPoints);

    mx=x;
    my=y;
    //LOG_INFO("LOOOOOL");
}

void Pen::onFingerUp ( )
{
    UndoHistory.push_front ( std::move ( m_path ) );
    // Also add this path to the global structure holding every primitives on screen

}


// Undo should not be part of pen but the top level drawing manager.
void Manager::undo ( )
{
    if ( UndoHistory.size  ( )  ) {
        redo_History. push_front ( undoMain.back ( );
    }

    // then redraw everything form the begining of undo history
    // You must have something holding every primitives on screen that is deeper than redo history
    ...
}

void Pen::redoPen ( )
{
    if  ( redo_History .size ( ) > 0 ) {
        Undo_History. push_front ( RedoMain.back ( );
        // Also add this path to the global structure holding every primitives on screen
    }

    // then redraw everything form the begining then everything from begin to end of undo history
}
```

Indeed adding undo history to anything is not that easy. You have to get deep understanding of your graphic engine.

Hope this can help.

Comment: mPath is actually a class holding floats. below is the mPath class please can u type how undo and redo are done with shared_ptr.

Comment: mPath::mPath()
    {

    }
    ////
    mPath::~mPath() {
     mlineHolder.clear();
      //  vector<fingerPos>(mlineHolder).swap(mlineHolder);
    }
    ///
    void mPath::addVert(fingerPos vert)
    {

     mlineHolder.push_back(vert);
    }
    ///
    vector<fingerPos> mPath::getPath()
    {
     return mlineHolder;
    }